# Values from last FOR loop over all, after FOR is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which get a json as parameter, build another json with some values from given json and return builded json.

```js
function getMyJSON(json) {
  var result = {
    lastUpdate: "",
    legends: null
  };

  result.legends = (new Array(json.legends.length)).fill({
    name: null,
    rgb: null,
    values: null
  });

  for (let j = 0; j < json.legends.length; j++) {
    result.legends[j].name = json.legends[j].name;
    result.legends[j].rgb = json.legends[j].rgb;
    result.legends[j].values = (new Array(10)).fill(0);
    console.log(result.legends[0].name); //PRINT ONLY FIRST ELEMENT
  }

  console.log(result.legends);

  return result;
}
```

The problem appear after `for loop` is done. All `result.legends` have the same value from the last `json.legends`

Here is how output look:

[image]

The `legends.name` of first element(`result.legends[0].name`) is changed after every loop.

At the end, all `legends.name` from `result` are equal with the last `legends.name` from `json`. Why?

I found on google that it is something about variable scope, but I can't figure it out how to do this.

Comment: Firstly, nothing about this is JSON. What you have is an object. Secondly, if you're trying to clone/amend the array try using `map()` instead, it's *much* simpler.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know it's not about json, but about that is my project. I'm not trying to clone array. I want to create another array with different fields from the given array. But I got the answer and the problem was at fill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need independent objects inside of the array. [`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) takes the same object reference and this leads to the same result in each object.

Instead of this, you could create a new array with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and map new objects with the second parameter for a callback.

```
result.legends = Array.from(
    { length: json.legends.length },
    _ => ({ name: null, rgb: null, values: null })
);
```

Comment: That is. Really thank you. I tried to figure out about 2 days. I thought `fill` will put a new instance on every position.

Answer (score 0):

@NinaScholz has described the problem and solved it, however as I mentioned in the comments on the question you can improve and simplify the logic by using `map()`:

```js
var obj = {
  legends: [{
    name: 'foo',
    rgb: 'C00'
  },{
    name: 'bar',
    rgb: 'FFF'
  },{
    name: 'fizz',
    rgb: 'CCFFCC'
  },{
    name: 'buzz',
    rgb: '000000'
  }]
}
console.log(getMyJSON(obj));

function getMyJSON(o) {
  return {
    lastUpdate: "",
    legends: o.legends.map(function(item) {
      return {
        name: item.name,
        rgb: item.rgb,
        values: (new Array(10)).fill(0)
      }
    })
  };
}
```